# HTML5 column width in nested table

Tags: html

I have a table, which I want to take up 80% of the width of its enclosing DIV.

The first column of the table is actually a table itself, and that columns first column should be as wide as the longest text in that column and the second should take the width up that 80% of the enclosing DIV.

I am totally stuck. It should be simple, but somehow the table only takes up as much width as is needed for the widest element in column 1, plus the widest in column 2 - not 80% of the enclosing DIV.

Why doesn't this work?

```
<div style="width:90%; margin:auto; margin-bottom:1%">
    <table width="80%" style="margin:auto">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="80%" style="margin:auto">
```

---

[Update[ The main point is that the tables don't have enough content to fill more than about 25% of the enclosing DIV, so I want to stretch the second column (of two) of the nested table.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a more complete table? And the enclosing DIV? What you have included is not very helpful in highlighting the issue.

Comment: btw, cellpadding is not supported in html5

Comment: You need to provide more code. Half a table is not useful. From what you have provided the table should display as you want it to: https://jsfiddle.net/w8bqs35s/

Comment: Thanks (+1) since you took the trouble to make a fiddle post, please  an answer. There is nothing ore to the table which would affect width

Answer (score 1):

you can add `word-break: break-word;` to the table element

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shirandror/b1wamshc/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle (+1). It's 11:30pm here now, so I will google in the morning got the meaning or ``word-break: break-word;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what browser you are using. When talking about HTML, CSS and Javascript behavior you should let us know of the browser you are using. I am using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) on Ubuntu and I copy-pasted your code and the table's columns that I added both had 50% of 80%(table) of 90%(div) of the width of the window.

I used `white-space: nowrap;` on the first cell to give it the width of it's text and used `width="100%"` on the second so that it encapsulates all of the remaining space.

Here's a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/aifrim/fwns1hk4/).

Comment: Thanks (+1). Of course, I want  across browser solution'

Comment: @Mawg I see that you have edited your question. Do you have a table nested within another table?

Comment: @Mawg please provide a more explicit example that the one you gave.